# Installation of Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I was trying to install Symfony2 on my mac following this tutorial : http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/book/installation.html

So i did : `curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`

It seemed to work although i got a PHP Warning :
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/intl.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/intl.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0`

For that i tried `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/` but it didn't seem to help.

The next command was : `sudo php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition /path/to/webroot/Symfony dev-master`

and the output was :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in phar:///Users/theofidry/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52
PHP Stack trace:
[...]
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in phar:///Users/theofidry/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52

Call Stack:
[...]
```

Si i change the memory_limit in the php.ini and retried the last command but the output is now :

```
HP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/intl.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/intl.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
#!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...
Could not create file /private/etc/composer.phar: fopen(/private/etc/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Download failed: fopen(/private/etc/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Downloading...
Could not create file /private/etc/composer.phar: fopen(/private/etc/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Download failed: fopen(/private/etc/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
Downloading...
Could not create file /private/etc/composer.phar: fopen(/private/etc/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Download failed: fopen(/private/etc/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
```

Anyone got an idea of how to resolve this mess ?

Comment: Sadly i've got no choice in that matter :p

Comment: Here it's apparently and clearly a problem of php extension install, not symfony. If you want to install intl, look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php

Comment: you have not clearly install intl. Either disable it, or install it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install intl extension y using pecl command and enable it in your php.ini

sudo pecl install intl

add the following in php.ini

extension="intl.so"